# VB.NET DataSet loop help

Tags: vb.net

Need a very simple code example, fewest lines possible.

I have a DataSet that contains 1 DataTable, and the DataTable contains only 1 row of data. I want to loop through all columns in that row and say:

Column name = column value

so for example if the column name is FAVORITE_FOOD and the value is pizza, I should display FAVORITE_FOOD = pizza

I can get the column name from column.ColumnName and the value from Rows(0).Item(0), but for the life of me I can't put it all together in a simple loop.

Comment: Need some answers before I can accept any now don't I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each DataColumn col In MyDataSet.Tables(0).Columns
    MsgBox( col.ColumnName & " = " & MyDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(col).ToString())
    ''#col.ColumnName = MyDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(col).ToString()
Next col
```

Comment: Sorry you imsunderstood. I edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: @JJD - I added a comment that shows the correct expression, but I need to know where you want to write each answer: back to the datatable? the console? an asp.net Response? somewhere else?

Comment: For this test I can pop up a msgbox.